# Are functions faster than commands in Neovim?

Tags: vim, neovim

[dein](https://github.com/Shougo/dein.vim) uses functions instead of commands even for functionality that's exposed to the user, which adds a little bit of extra typing when you work on your `init.vim`. Is there a reason for that? Are functions faster than commands?

Answer (score 4):

As most custom commands invoke one (or more) user-defined functions, **there is a tiny performance benefit to functions, but that doesn't matter at all**.

Commands more than make up for this by being quicker to type, allowing (custom) completion, being more discoverable, etc. All caveats about premature optimization (*don't do it*) apply here.

---

You refer to the *dein* package manager. I would guess that interaction with it is only (mostly) needed during startup, by invoking it in your `~/.vimrc`. By using (autoload) functions, you don't need to `:runtime plugin/dein.vim` to define the custom commands; just having *dein* in the `'runtimepath'` is enough to invoke its functions.

Also, this avoids polluting the commands namespace with commands that are not / rarely used interactively. Some plugin authors also just have their own, idiosyncratic style. For a definite answer, you'd have to ask the author :-)